# "As well you know"?

Tags: phrases

Wonder whether or not the usage "as well you know" is correct, or is it "as you well know"? The latter seems normal but I seem to remember hearing the former.

Comment: In my experience, you could have either. It’s a similar structure to "As well he may". I can’t find any easy official reference, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P1. colloq.
 a. **you know.**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/104157?redirectedFrom=you%20know#eid138769179)

> (a) Used parenthetically, usually following the main statement
>   (frequently with emphatic, persuasive, or reproving intent): as you
>   know (or may like to or should know) is the case.

"As well you know" is correct as is "as you well know". The latter is heard more often, but the former is used too.

Answer (score 1):

The former is pseudo-poetic and idiomatic at the same time, the latter is merely technically correct.

> As well you should

and

> As well she might

are similar: variations on the same grammatical theme.